# Why is for loop and if statement not working correctly for two lists in python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

I have some data to read and I don't know why my code is not working. I want to read multiple netcdf files and store them in a ds. Here my simplified input (I have ~400 entries in my lists names and file_paths, not 4):

```
names = ['a','b','c','d']
file_paths = ['file_path_a','file_path_b',file_path_c',file_path_d']
number_of_measurements = []

for a, b in zip(names, file_paths):
    a = xr.open_dataset(b, group='data')
    number_of_measurements.append(len(a.datetime))
```

I want to remove the files_paths and the entries in the number_of_measurements when len(a.datetime) == 0 (this means that no measurements where done). I need the number_of_measurements to create a counter for an other function.

I tried this:

```
for i, j in zip(number_of_measurements, file_paths):
    if i == 0:
       file_paths.remove(j)
       number_of_measurements.remove(i)
```

This seems to work but not always, before this for loop I had number_of_measurements.count(0) = 33 and after the for loop I had number_of_measurements = 4. When I did the for loop twice I had the wanted number_of_measurements.count(0) = 0. Why is it not working correctly for the first time?

I also tried this within the first for loop, but it is not working either and I don't know why:

```
for a, b in zip(names, file_paths):
    a = xr.open_dataset(b, group='data')
    if len(a.datetime) == 0:
        file_paths.remove(b)
    else:
        number_of_measurements.append(len(a.datetime))
```

Comment: Mutating the sequence when iterating over it is tricky. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=loop#for-statements

Comment: Ah ok thank you @Shanavas M, I solved it by creating new lists:
`file_paths_correct = []
number_of_measurements_correct = []
for i, j in zip(number_of_measurements, file_paths):
    if i != 0:
       file_pahts_correct.append(j) 
       number_of_measurements_correct.append(i)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generally not advisable to modify an sequence when iterating over itself.
For example:

```
li = [1, 2, 3]
for x in li:
    l.remove(x)
```

One might expect `li` is now an empty list. However,

```
>>> li
>>> [2]
```

This is due to how list iterator works. In the first iteration of the for loop, `x` is assigned the first element of the list `1`. Then `1` is removed from the list. `li` now holds `[2, 3]`. When the for loop moves on to the second iteration, `x` is assigned the second element of the list. But the second element of the list is `3` now. Hence `2` is never removed from the list.

For your purpose, you can build a new list instead of modifying the original though.

```
number_of_measurements = []
file_paths_new = []
for b in file_paths:
    x = len(xr.open_dataset(b, group='data').datetime)
    if x != 0:
        number_of_measurements.append(x)
        file_paths_new.append(x)
file_paths = file_paths_new
```